# Can I set a "deny" rule on a Windows privilege?

Tags: windows-server-2008, security

Windows privileges ([examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) are assigned to accounts and groups, and by default the "SERVICE" built-in principal has a couple of privileges assigned, such as the "impersonate user" privilege.

I want to create a restricted account for a service that doesn't have this privilege. Can I somehow set a "deny" rule for this privilege, just like one can use with file ACLs? Or do I have to remove "SERVICE" from the list of SeImpersonatePrivilege grantees to achieve this? (something I'd rather avoid if I can, since this can conceivably break other services)

<sub>Edited to correct a brain-cloud-induced conflation of two completely unrelated things into one monstrosity of a question.</sub>

Comment: I know this is an old thread OP, but I read something that made me think of this question and you might enjoy it (the accepted answer):

http://serverfault.com/questions/70484/troubleshooting-windows-group-policy-permissions

Comment: @RyanRies Fortunately, unlike forums this place actually welcomes keeping everything in one place, regardless of how old the question is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Windows privileges are completely different from file system ACLs.

You use the Windows API to programmatically adjust Windows privileges. There is no GUI. They are binary; the privileges can be added or taken away, but there's no "Deny" mechanism like there is in NTFS ACLs, etc.

For instance, I needed to import advapi32.dll into my code to access the GetTokenInformation() function, which among other things contains the privileges for an account of a given SID.

I'm not sure that I agree with your assertion that the domain\Users group has the SeImpersonatePrivilege by default.  That would fly in the face of any attempt at securing a Windows environment.

Check your local security policy and your domain policies, and expand Computer Config -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment and check the "Impersonate a client after authentication" setting.  I do not see the Users group listed anywhere.

Comment: +1 - I concur re: "I'm not sure ... that the domain\Users group has the SeImpersonatePrivilege by default." They do not. Somebody has munged up the default GPOs in the OP's domain.

Comment: @EvanAnderson You guys are right, I wanted to ask about a *service*! I got confused by a completely separate issue, where the entire drive D:\ was readable by any member of "Users", and hence absolutely every authenticated user, but that was easily fixable with ACLs. Question edited.

Comment: P.S. "There is no GUI" - I'd certainly call "User Rights Assignment" a GUI, vehemently so after managing permissions on a headless CentOS over SSH. That dialog is as GUI as GUIs get :)